# Prism MVVM, Should I put IRegionManager in ViewModel or some where else?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, prism

I have a ViewModel that can create another ViewModel.

I want to set this ViewModel as the data context of existing View, then Navigate to that View.

### In MyViewModel

```
private void CreateNewOrder()
{
    var order = new OrderViewModel(new Order(){/* setup some things */});
    // another ViewModel subscribes to MyCustomEvent
    this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyCustomEvent>().publish(order); 
    this.regionManager.RequestNavigate("DetailRegion", new Uri("OrderView", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

The problem is ...

- My ViewModel needs reference to the region's name, and the View's name.
- "DetailRegion" must contain the "OrderView" object.
- DetailView.DataContext is set to OrderViewModel (using aggregate event subscription)

Is this tight coupling?

I've spent sometime looking in the Prism Quickstart project and found the "Controller" or something that is too complicated.

I just want to simplify decoupling View-ViewModel.

Comment: MVC isn't that complicated.  I'd stick with the Quickstart thing that you found.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you have added to the ViewModel, belongs in a controller.

- ViewModels are dumb containers that hold a certain shape of data. *They do not know where the data comes from or where it is displayed.*
- Views display a certain shape of data via bindings to a view model. *They do not know where the data comes from, only how to display it.*
- Models hold real data. *They do not know where is is consumed.*

So what's missing from this picture? 
 - Controllers publish and listen for events and fetch data for the
   ViewModel from a Model. They also control navigation.

It really should have been designed as MVCVM. I see no end of misuse of MVVM through the absence of controller classes. Give the Prism Quickstart another go.

> Just to clarify how a controller fits into the MVVM picture, here is an example
>   scenario:
>
> - Controller is registered and initialized by the module or app*.
> - Controller subscribes to a "show details" message.
> - Controller receives a "show details" message.
> - Controller constructs a "details" VM, fills it with data and assigns any ICommand properties to code in the controller (e.g. pretty much all app
>     logic is in controllers).
> - Controller triggers display of the appropriate view, supplying the VM.
> - View data is bound to VM. Buttons are bound to ICommands in the VM.
> - User edits data and clicks submit. The submit code is in the Controller and decides what to do with the new data in the VM.

*Note: VMs and views do not need to hang around waiting for messages, so only controllers actually need to exist for the lifetime of the app (i.e. very small footprint). This is great for mobile apps and generally a good thing for any app.

Comment: Separating the logic to fetch data into a several controller will only complicate the already complex MVVM class structure. When you are doing it right (using an appropriate base class for your ViewModels), there won't be any reason to have the code separated.

Comment: @PVitt: Sorry, but that is not the case. MVVM and MVCVM are both very simple class structures. In practice the separation (using controllers for logic) simplifies large applications and the ongoing maintenance. Hiding "logic" in a VM base class is a recipe for making a complex mess.

Comment: When you design your UI you will have loads of views and corresponding view models. Several Models require their own view models so this alone gives you masses of classes. When the 2 lines to get the data from the model are seperated into their own class then you will nearly double your classes. And hiding logic in bases classes is what the concept of inheritance is made for.

Comment: When your design your *app* you have one class per distinct view (shared), one class per distinct ViewModel (shared) and one class per controller. There may only be one controller handling logic for multiple views and view models, but that is not the point. Hiding "logic" in a base class it not what inheritance is for. It is for implementing "Is-a" relationships. Arguing the benefits of not doing this because it looks like more typing/work is pretty pointless. In practice complex apps are easier to write/manage with controllers. I am stating this from experience, feel free to disagree :)

Comment: A UserViewModel is a ViewModel. A UserListViewModel is a ViewModel. A ValueViewModel is a ViewModel. Every ViewModel needs to have a method to get it's data. So why do I have to implement this in a seperate controller instead of the superclass ViewModel?

Comment: "Every ViewModel needs to have a method to get it's data" is wrong. ViewModels should have no idea where the data comes from, only the shape of it. They are, and should be, just dumb containers. The controller obtains data from Models and stuffs it in the ViewModels. From the way you describe your systems you are not doing  test-driven development. TDD is made 10 times harder by a lack of separate controllers. Feel free to ignore my advice, but I have done it both ways and know what works better. Why don't you try it yourself, then come back. It really does make more sense once you try it :)